# Doctrine DQL dynamic ORDER BY parameter

Tags: orm, doctrine, sql-order-by, dql

Im trying to pass the ORDER BY column as a parameter in DQL, like below:

```
$this->em->createQuery("SELECT t FROM Entities\Topic t ORDER BY :order")
     ->setParameters( array('order' => 't.name') )->getResult();
```

I guess it doesn't work because setParameter will escape :order, however the below solution doesn't seem very good:

```
$order = 't.name'; // Dynamic value
$this->em->createQuery("SELECT t FROM Entities\Topic t ORDER BY $order")
     ->getResult();
```

Is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

In that case use Doctrines [Querybuilder](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/query-builder.html):

```
$order = 't.name'; // Dynamic value

$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('t')
   ->from('Entities\Topic', 't')
   ->orderBy($order);
```

Comment: @Dennis sorry if this answer hurt your feelings ;) no, seriously - if you have a query which is built dynamically - thats a real use case for the query builder. But on the other hand, I think your solution actually is ok. I wouldnt do variable interpolation, that looks too unclear. If I were you, just do: `->createQuery('SELECT t FROM Entities\Topic t ORDER BY ' . $order)` and be done with it.

Comment: @Max, is this way safe from SQL Injection?!

Comment: @LucianoMammino no you should definately have a whitelist for the allowed order by values

Comment: @Max, I've just talked with a friend about this topic and he clearly pointed out that it would be better talking about "DQL injection". Anyway we agreed that whitelisting is the best solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is an old question but until today this "problem" still exists. So, if you want to use dynamic ordering, you should use the doctrine queryBuilder.

I recently tested the current doctrine types on which one could be used for dynamic ordering.
In my case I set the order column in the dql and only wanted to inject ASC/DESC.

Now, here is the test output:

```
DQL: SELECT w FROM App\Entity\Worker w ORDER BY w.id :order
Type "array" is invalid
Type "ascii_string" is invalid
Type "bigint" is invalid
Type "binary" is invalid
Type "blob" is invalid
Type "boolean" is invalid
Type "date" is invalid
Type "date_immutable" is invalid
Type "dateinterval" is invalid
Type "datetime" is invalid
Type "datetime_immutable" is invalid
Type "datetimetz" is invalid
Type "datetimetz_immutable" is invalid
Type "decimal" is invalid
Type "float" is invalid
Type "guid" is invalid
Type "integer" is invalid
Type "json" is invalid
Type "object" is invalid
Type "simple_array" is invalid
Type "smallint" is invalid
Type "string" is invalid
Type "text" is invalid
Type "time" is invalid
Type "time_immutable" is invalid
```

I'm using Symfony 5.3 and Doctrine 2.9

If someone is interested in the code, I used to test: I simply created a doctrine entity inside my symfony project. Then I created a test method inside the related repository object:

```
public function testOrder(string $order = 'ASC'): array
{
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
        'SELECT w
        FROM App\Entity\Worker w
        ORDER BY w.id :order'
    );
    // map taken from: vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/Type.php:101
    $doctrineTypeMap = [
        Types::ARRAY,
        Types::ASCII_STRING,
        Types::BIGINT,
        Types::BINARY,
        Types::BLOB,
        Types::BOOLEAN,
        Types::DATE_MUTABLE,
        Types::DATE_IMMUTABLE,
        Types::DATEINTERVAL,
        Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE,
        Types::DATETIME_IMMUTABLE,
        Types::DATETIMETZ_MUTABLE,
        Types::DATETIMETZ_IMMUTABLE,
        Types::DECIMAL,
        Types::FLOAT,
        Types::GUID,
        Types::INTEGER,
        Types::JSON,
        Types::OBJECT,
        Types::SIMPLE_ARRAY,
        Types::SMALLINT,
        Types::STRING,
        Types::TEXT,
        Types::TIME_MUTABLE,
        Types::TIME_IMMUTABLE,
    ];
    print_r('DQL: ' . $query->getDQL() . "<br/>");
    foreach ($doctrineTypeMap as $mappedType) {
        try {
            $query->setParameter('order', $order, $mappedType);
            print_r('Type "' . $mappedType . '" is ');
            $query->getSQL();
            print_r('valid' . "<br/>");
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            print_r('invalid' . "<br/>");
        }
    }
    // Prevent symfony from rendering a view
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding the following method to the repository, also using the [Query Builder](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/reference/query-builder.html):

```
class SomeEntityRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    private function addOrderBy(QueryBuilder $qb, string $field, string $dir, string $alias = 'g'): void
    {
        if (property_exists($this->getClassName(), $field)) {
            $dir = strtoupper($dir) === Criteria::DESC ? Criteria::DESC : Criteria::ASC;
            $qb->addOrderBy($alias . '.' . $field, $dir);
        }
    }
}
```